# Why unique count in kibana visualize chart is incorrect?

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana-4

my kibana version is 4.5.
my elastic version is 2.3.1.

see the pic1 .the uv is 7665.
but see the pic2.the uv is 7845.
why diffrent ?
kibana unique count seeing not correct.
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: Elastic version 2.7.3 does not exist, did you mean 1.7.3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these charts are based on live data, then I doubt both the graphs cannot show the same count since you're having two different **time-range** in both the graphs.

In the first one your time range is *yesterday*, where as in the second one your trying to have an **auto-refresh** every minute which shows as paused. I'm assuming that you're dealing with live data so that some records might have slipped through, by the time you paused. If not I cannot see any chances of these two showing two different values.

Just being curious, how do you know that the correct count for `uv` should be 7665 since I can't see the exact value of `uv` from the snapshot of the graph? Did you double check from your ES indice through a query?

**EDIT**:

Interestingly **Unique counts** are based on the [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation), which is designed to work efficiently across very large amounts of data and delivers an approximate result, which may why your results vary. You can maybe try increasing the *[precision_threshold](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3494)*.

> To get a more correct value, add a something like: {"precision_threshold": 1000} to the "JSON Input" box for the aggregation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this threshold has a maximum of I believe 40000. Any unique count beyond that will become increasingly fuzzy. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html And, in OP's case, setting this value to 1000 will not help because his unique count is already  > 7k. He will have to set it higher than that

Comment: i set {"precision_threshold": 10000} .